# How to get account info from my local private rpc?

Tags: rpc, validator, jsonrpc-api, getaccountinfo

I built private rpc node in mainnet and it catches up well.
I want to get account info from localhost, but it gets error.

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": 1,
"method": "getAccountInfo",
"params": [
  "vines1vzrYbzLMRdu58ou5XTby4qAqVRLmqo36NKPTg",
  {
    "encoding": "base58"
  }
]}
```

error message

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found"},"id":1}
```

I can get rpc response well with method like "getBalance", "getGenesisHash", "getLeaderSchedule".

I cannot with "getAccountInfo", "getMultipleAccounts", "getLatestBlockhash".

My node is running with

```
solana-validator \
--identity ~/validator-keypair.json \
--vote-account ~/vote-account-keypair.json \
--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--known-validator 7cVfgArCheMR6Cs4t6vz5rfnqd56vZq4ndaBrY5xkxXy \
--known-validator DDnAqxJVFo2GVTujibHt5cjevHMSE9bo8HJaydHoshdp \
--known-validator Ninja1spj6n9t5hVYgF3PdnYz2PLnkt7rvaw3firmjs \
--known-validator wWf94sVnaXHzBYrePsRUyesq6ofndocfBH6EmzdgKMS \
--known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
--known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
--known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
--known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
--ledger ~/ledger \
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
--private-rpc \
--no-voting \
--rpc-bind-address 127.0.0.1 \
--rpc-port 8899 \
--wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
--log ~/log/solana-validator.log \
--accounts ~/account \
--limit-ledger-size \
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

After all, I could get response with --full-rpc-api option.